# Vizhnitzer Rebbe's Prayer for Israeli Soldiers

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, nuschaot, state-of-israel, mi-sheberach

On the first Shabboth following the [Simhhat Torah Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Hamas-led_attack_on_Israel), the Vizhnitzer Rebbe, R. Yisrael Hager recited a special prayer for the soldiers in the IDF. It was not the commonly recited Mi Sheberakh composed by R. Shelomo Goren, rather it was one composed R. Menahem Mendel Reuven Gefner around the 1948 War of Independence. The [Jerusalem Post](https://www.jpost.com/judaism/article-777143) translates it as follows:

> He who blessed our ancestors, Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, may He bless
> and safeguard and assist and protect and save all our brethren, the
> house of Israel, who stand in battle against those who hate Israel. As
> the entire congregation blesses them and prays for them. In merit of
> this, may the Holy One, blessed be He, watch over them and save them
> from all harm, and cause peoples to be subject to them, and let five
> of them pursue 100, and 100 of them pursue 10,000, and wherever they
> turn they will succeed, and our enemies will fall before them by the
> sword, and they will return in peace to their tents. [God will] cause
> them to recuperate, heal them, strengthen them, and revive them. And
> may He send them from heaven complete recovery for all their limbs and
> their sinews, together with all Jews who are ill, a healing of the
> soul and a healing of the body, now, soon, and in the near future, and
> let us say amen.
>
> And whoever has fallen into captivity, may the Holy One, blessed be
> He, be filled with mercy for them, and grant them mercy before their
> captors, and rescue the prisoner from confinement, and proclaim
> release for the captives and liberation for the imprisoned, and
> speedily return them to their homes in peace. Amen.

Does anyone know where the original Hebrew text can be found?

Comment: https://orot.ac.il/sites/default/files/amadot/7-7.pdf and https://www.jstor.org/stable/aleisefer.24-25.297

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks for bringing my attention to these! Very informative on the larger topic